# adding strings and numbers in javascript

Tags: javascript, concatenation

The script below is an example I came across in a tutorial. It's supposed to show what happens to a number when it gets too big.

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var myNumber = 2; 
    var txt = "";
    while (myNumber != Infinity) {
        myNumber = myNumber * myNumber;
        txt = txt + myNumber + "<br>";
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
}
</script>
```

And here is the output:

```
4
16
256
65536
4294967296
18446744073709552000
3.402823669209385e+38
1.157920892373162e+77
1.3407807929942597e+154
Infinity
```

My two questions are basically

1) In the second iteration of the while loop, txt already has a character 4 in it (because a string plus a number is a string in Javascript) and then we add 16 to that string. Shouldn't we get 416 and so on?

2) Why does the break (br) element need to have a quotation marks around it?

Comment: 1) At 2nd iteration, your txt becomes `4<br>16<br>`, so its not `416`

Comment: `txt = txt + myNumber + <br>` would be `variable = variable + variable + variable` and `<br>` is not a variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) No.  In the second iteration, `txt` is `"4<br>"`.  Adding `16` results in `"4<br>16"`

2) That's a string literal  like any other string literal.

Comment: @Rockstar5645 you are getting 416. You are just putting a `<br>` in between them like SLaks said. Thus there is a hard return between the two numbers. Add `console.log(txt)` inside the loop and you'll better see the numbers being added together.